# add some member to a list with prolog

Tags: list, prolog

i have some facts.I want to make a list of members of this facts and show these members by function.but i don't know how to do it. i try this code :

```
hasDiabet(mina).
hasvitaminD(milk).
hasvitaminD(eggs).
addto(X,L,[X|L]).
hasvitamin(L):-hasvitaminD(x),addto(X,L,L),hasvitamin(L).
eat(Y,X):-hasvitaminD(X).
```

here i want to make a list of thing that hasvitaminD -> milk and egg. and show this when i write something like eat(mina,X). but when i test my code the output is milk. help please
 thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

some problems:

```
hasvitamin(L):-
  hasvitaminD(x), % x must be uppercase for it to be a Variable
  addto(X,L,L),   % will never succeed, since Prolog variable are *immutable*
  hasvitamin(L).  % recursing with the same input would lead to infinite loop
```

from your problem description, I think you should learn about [all solutions builtins](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions).

Try

```
?- findall(X, hasvitaminD(X), L).
```